# NHibernate.Event.IPostDeleteEventListener not working good with transactions

Tags: c#, nhibernate, transactions, acid

I have a NHibernate-mapped class that holds binary data bound to a file on disk. Business logic is very simple:

- When object is stored in the database, the blob is written to a file properly named to match object ID
- When object is loaded from DB, blob is filled with file contents
- When object is deleted from DB, file is deleted too

I used an IPostDeleteEventListener to handle the three situations

The only problem is that if the transaction, for some reason, is rolled back after `Session.Delete()` the file has been already deleted but the record is kept into the DB, which results in FileNotFoundException when application tries to (re)load the non-deleted object.

Also, but that's not a big matter, if transaction is canceled after insert, I get a garbage file.

What can I do to perform these file system operations **only** when the transaction is being committed?

[Add] MAYBE... I said maybe, I found a workaround. The `ITransaction` interface exposes a `RegisterSynchronization` method which accepts an interface as argument. MAYBE that can be the workaround: storing/deleting the file only after completion of transaction. I need to investigate more, but it seems there is no engineered way to hook to commit/rollback directly from NHibernate event listener subsystem.

Comment: Hello, any progress on this issue? I saw your issue on nhibernate forum [NH-2523] but it seems that there was no progress since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the filesystem is not transactional and there's no "post-commit" event exposed, it's better to do it *outside* of NH's event system (i.e. in a higher-level layer)

Comment: Hmmm.... bad thing to read... Would you agree that NH developers should definitely implement a post-commit event to handle these siutations? I'm starting to have a couple of ideas based on delegates/lambdas. Anyway, waiting for other opinions on the subject

Comment: "the NH developers" won't implement it just because you'd find it useful. You can provide a patch, along with the tests, and make a reasonable case for it, or just use the patched version.

Comment: I think I used the wrong words... "Do you agree that this is something that should be definitely be suggested to NH developers for implementation?". +1 to your comment, anyway I filed a report but I don't think I have the NH core's knowledge to contribute with patch, even if I have the skills and some time :(

Comment: In all honesty... it's unlikely to happen. My opinion is that the logic you are trying to call from NH does not belong there, regardless.